# Табу - как слово попало в русский язык?

Tags: этимология

Как известно, "табу" - это запрет. Причем употребляется это слово далеко не только в значении какого-то первобытного запрета, хотя все-таки имеет значение запрета абсолютного, не подлежащего обсуждению. Есть даже производное от него "табуированный".  
А вот интересно, из какого языка это слово происходит изначально и, главное, как оно попало в русский язык?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

В русский слово пришло, скорее всего, из английского, а в английский - из тонганского языка (tapu), при посещении одного из островов Тонга Джеймсом Куком (1777 г.), которому это слово было растолковано (в описаниях он воспроизвёл его как 'taboo'). Однако, слово присутствовало тогда и в других языках той же группы (полинезийской группы языков), например, в фиджийском (tabu) и в языке Маори (tapu, Новая Зеландия).

Answer (score 0):

Здесь иврит. **טָאבּוּ** /*табу*/ **запрет** (*религиозный*, *общественный*). Смотреть: **ИРИС - словарь д-ра Баруха Подольского**, интернет-ссылка:   [link text](http://www.slovar.co.il/translate.php).